# Controlling ABB robot in RobotStudio using ROS

Tags: ros, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to simulate the ABB  driver by running a simulation of the ABB robot on RobotStudio.
The plan to do this is to run RobotStudio on one PC, and then connect another PC to the first one via ethernet and run the ROS nodes on the second PC.
I have tried looking for ways to do this, but I am not sure how to set up the configurations on the RobotStudio end of things.
May I know how it may be possible to connect the simulated Robot Controller in RobotStudio to the second PC via ethernet?
The "second PC" mentioned is running ROS Noetic on a Linux OS (Ubuntu 20.04 distro).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379457/controlling-abb-robot-in-robotstudio-using-ros/) by [MohammadHashmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/75448/mohammadhashmi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-03**:
Which driver will you be using?

Have you found any other Q&As here on ROS Answers about this topic?

**Comment by [MohammadHashmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/75448/mohammadhashmi/) on 2021-06-03**:
I will be using the older version of the ABB driver. I have found Q&As related to this topic but none that provide insight into how to manage on the RobotStudio end of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The installation and setup tutorials for `abb_driver` have a tutorial dedicated to setting up the virtual robot controller: [abb_driver/Tutorials/RobotStudio: Using Simulated Robot in Robot Studio](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver/Tutorials/RobotStudio).

In essence, a few tweaks are necessary, but after that it would be exactly like how you'd run things with a real robot and IRC5.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MohammadHashmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/75448/mohammadhashmi/) on 2021-06-03**:
Thank you. I am trying it out right now. I will keep this post updated on any new discoveries.

**Comment by [mohitrochlani](https://answers.ros.org/users/120438/mohitrochlani/) on 2022-10-16**:
hey MohammadHashmi , any update on your work were you able to run the Simulation on Robot studio using ROS??